# Pretty URLs for JSFiddles

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there a way to get your fiddles to have a URL with the name you choose in the fiddle options. For example, I think I should be able to have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/cose65dh/) fiddle use "Utility" in the URL rather than cose65dh.

Is it possible?

Dummy code to include fiddle:

```
code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [the settings page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar) does not have any settings to change the URL that is generated.